# Result of tar -czf

Tags: linux, zip, compression, gzip, tar

I need to put the extension for the compressed file, either .tgz or .gz. But I don't know whether this command

```
tar -czf somefile.XXX some/path/to/dir
```

makes a tarball before compression, or all files in the directory are compressed first then they are tarballed up.

Should .tgz == .tar.gz, and .gz == .zip?

Comment: You should be able to type "man tar" at the command line to read the tar manual; under the "-z" option on my system, the manual says, "Compress the resulting archive with gzip(1)". You can also check what type the resulting file is by, for example, `file somefile.tgz`; that should tell you the file is "gzip compressed data"; the results for a non-gzipped tar archive would be "POSIX tar data".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes a tar archive before compression.

The suffix `.tgz` is a shorthand for `.tar.gz`, which is equivalent to first making the `.tar` with `tar -cf somefile.tar some/path/to/dir`, and then compressing that with `gzip somefile.tar`.

Comment: ...which makes the most sense, as compression algorithms typically work better the more data they have to compress. They can spot more recurring patterns and only have to store one dictionary, so providing one big tarball and then gzipping it will produce smaller results.